# Solve analytically an equation with Lambert function

Tags: lambert-w

Can this equation be solved analytically, maybe using Lambert $W$ function?
$$(1-x)^{1-x}(1+x)^{1+x}=k$$

The problem is that I can't reformulate the equation in a way that lets me use Lambert's $W$ function: $f(x)e^{f(x)}$.

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: :/ I don't think you *can* get it into that form.

Comment: $x^x = y$ can be inverted to $x = e^{W(\log y)}$. Maybe this can be used?